# React useeffect

Tags: reactjs, useeffect

Подскажите как мне сделать что бы на разных страницах работали разные useEffect
App.js

```
const [chek, setChek] = useState("filtrnew");
useEffect(() => {
        if(chek === "filtrnew"){
        window.addEventListener('popstate', () => goBack());
        }bridge.subscribe(({ detail: { type, data }}) => {
            if (type === 'VKWebAppUpdateConfig') {
                setScheme(data.scheme)
            }
        });
```

Вторая страница Filtr.js

```
function Sz({chek}) {
if(chek === "filtrnew"){
            setChek("no");
        }
useEffect(() => {
            if (chek === "no"){
            window.addEventListener('popstate', () => goBack11());}
        })
```

Но он все ровно работает только по useEffect который в app.js не реагируя на то что я поменял переменную chek

Comment: https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

use-effect принимает втарым аргументом массив зависимостей, если надо вызвать единожды то передаешь пустой массив, если надо реагировать на изменения состояния то в этот массив передаешь все состояния(в данном случее только chek) на которые должен срабативать еффект.